# Boost with Cmake on linux(ubuntu)

Tags: boost, linker, cmake

This my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
add_definitions(-std=c++11)
find_package(Boost 1.55.0 COMPONENTS filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(bst main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(bst ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

When i execute `cmake ..` in my `build` directory , `cmake` successfully generates files .

But when i run `make` in `build` directory i get following errors :

```
amin@aminux:~/Documents/boost_test/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target bst
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/bst.dir/main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable bst
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/bst.dir/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to    symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.55.0: error   adding       symbols: DSO missing from command line
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bst] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/bst.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

in my `main.cpp` source file i just called  `boost::filesystem::is_directory` function for testing  `boost` .

Comment: Add system component find_package(Boost 1.55.0 COMPONENTS filesystem system REQUIRED) - this should help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You also should add boost::system library component in your CMakeLists.txt file

> find_package(Boost 1.55.0 COMPONENTS filesystem **system** REQUIRED)

Comment: You deserve more UP my friend!